# Select Distinct and show records where X column is not the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with a structure of:

[image]

I am struggling to write a query to show me where 'Supp' is different. 
(Supp Should be the same for all records, So i need to identify records effected to correct) 
The table contains more than 55,000 lines

Just a list of Codes where Supp is not the same for each of the Location would be sufficient. 
Selecting distinct or group by but unsure how to query the Supp if different. 
For example with the above Data: **1478** and **5689** would be the effected lines.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Supp) > 1`.

Comment: ```HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Supp) < 2 ``` Should give you only the records that are different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the simplest case, to get a list of `Code`s that have more than one `Supp`:

```
SELECT Code
  FROM testtable
  GROUP BY Code
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Supp) >= 2
```

Output:

```
1478
5689
```

If you want to get the full rows (or partial by changing `SELECT *`), try something like:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM testtable a
    INNER JOIN (
                SELECT Code
                  FROM testtable
                  GROUP BY Code
                  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Supp) >= 2
                ) b ON b.Code = a.Code
```

Output:

```
Location    Code    Supp    Ref
1           1478    CAM001  203442
2           1478    CAM001  203442
99          1478    COL001  203442
1           5689    SAM001  65789
2           5689    SUL001  65789
99          5689    SUL001  65789
```

See this in action on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ba4c5/1).